# Magento PWA: Which to use venia or vue storefront

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio

I am looking for better options to implement PWA with my M2.3 store. Searched and found that we have 2 options (Venia and Vue) right now which provide a basic structure to start with PWA. While Vue have much features and options in it.

I am confused with which i should use ? I dont have experience in either React or Vue and On my store i have various custom pages and forms that i have built for client requirement using Using Custom Extensions which need to implement in PWA theme as well.

Can you suggest me which to follow ? which will be good in development and future secure ?

Comment: Suggest you go with Vue because still not well document release PWA from Magento side.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the Vue Storefront - there are more implementations available, more case studies and the community is incredibly helpful. You'll find more arguments on [VS blog](https://medium.com/the-vue-storefront-journal/).

Comment: In addition you can find an actual list of all the VueStorefront implementations here: https://github.com/frqnck/awesome-vue-storefront